# Angular watch multiple values, without ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

Is it possible to watch multiple $scope values in same `$watch`, without using ng-repeat? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wr4twkzm/)

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlParent">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="prov1">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="prov2">
            <div>{{prov1}}</div>
            <div>{{prov2}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    app.controller('ctrlParent', function ($scope) {

    $scope.prov1 = true;
    $scope.prov2 = true;
    $scope.ids = {};

    $scope.$watch('prov1', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != oldValue) {
            console.log("wee");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From angular 1.3 onwards you can use `$scope.$watchGroup` as follows:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['prov1', 'prov2'], function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue != oldValue) {
        console.log("wee");
    }
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wr4twkzm/1/